# Two empty keys PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to ask what would the output of the following fragment of script be?

```
$list = array(-10=>1, 2, 3, "first_name"=>"mike", 4, 5);
unset($list);
$list[] = 6;
$list[] = 7;
print_r($list);
$list = array_values($list);
print_r($list);
```

I would say the output would be just 7?
Also as there are two empty keys, does the first one get the key [0] and the next [1], or does the second key assume [0]

Comment: why not you run this code and check.. check here:- https://eval.in/553503

Comment: can you not run php? is this some sort of quiz or joke?

Comment: @Anant I have some problems getting a php working, I'm still learning php

Comment: An empty key when defining a new value in an array assigns it with the key as the next available numeric index.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins Thank you, I've just understood it, the next empty key  gets a key of 1 more and then assigned

Comment: @Anant Thank you for the help

Comment: welcome. https://eval.in/553507. check this one also

Comment: See the **Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax** section of the manual; http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty `[]` operator will add a value at the end of the list, which previously is emptied by `unset`. I.e., the list will contain 6 and 7, and printing it will print `Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 7 )`, which is done twice.